# Need some clarification about Mongo Realm and Mongo Atlas. And App user data

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm, mongodb-atlas

I am new to app development and I've been looking into using MongoDB Atlas and MongoDB Realm. A few questions I couldn't find answers from their documentation, hopefully someone can clarify for me.

- Is it correct to think Mongo Realm is client DB and it uses sync to the MongoDB Atlas, so if I make a React Native app using Realm, then user store/retrieve data from one device, and can pick up from another device (if they logged in with the same account)?
- If point 1 is yes, then if I want to make a web app as well and skip Realm and only use Mongo Atlas, can I use the data synced from Realm? E.g. a task list created with my React Native app in Realm and synced to Atlas, can I create a web app and query synced data stored in Atlas direct say with Mongoose?
- If point 2 is true, how can I access app user from Atlas, it seems it only exists only in Realm, what's approach here?
- Final point is, for this kind of cross platform app, what's the best approach?

Many thanks,

Comment: MongoDB Realm is many things.  Realm is a mobile database.  Realm is also a web development library that allows synchronization from a mobile database back and forth to an Atlas database.  Realm is a series of APIs for iOS (Swift) and/or Android (Java or Kotlin).  Realm is a development stack inside of MongoDB Atlas with hosting capabilities.  Realm is serverless lambda-style functions in Atlas.  Realm is a term used by MongoDB to support database at-the-edge devices and communication back to Atlas as a mobile-first solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on implementing an app with the setup you describe.

> 1. Is it correct to think Mongo Realm is client DB and it uses sync to the MongoDB Atlas, so if I make a React Native app using Realm, then user store/retrieve data from one device, and can pick up from another device (if they logged in with the same account)?

Yes! You can try this easily with the [Task Tracker App by MongoDB Realm Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/react-native/)

> 2. if I want to make a web app as well and skip Realm and only use Mongo Atlas, can I use the data synced from Realm? E.g. a task list created with my React Native app in Realm and synced to Atlas, can I create a web app and query synced data stored in Atlas direct say with Mongoose?

Yes! - Realm Sync does not support React Native Web as far as I know, therefore creating a Web App with React or Next.js is a good alternative as MongoDB Atlas data synced from mobile devices via Realm Sync can be easily be accessed in this way. I am currently looking at the following approach: [How to Integrate MongoDB Into Your Next.js App](https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/nextjs-with-mongodb/)

> 3. how can I access app user from Atlas, it seems it only exists only in Realm, what's approach here?

Try the above mentioned example app with a few users and this will become more clear to you. In this case the MongoDB Atlas database will be 'partitioned' by userID making it easy to get just the data you want for the web app. Look into [Partition Atlas Data into Realms](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sync/partitioning/) to understand this more fully.

> 4. for this kind of cross platform app, what's the best approach?

Well what is the *best* approach is difficult to answer as the question is too broad, and it depends a lot on what the app is for and how it is used.

Personally I have good reasons for choosing Realm Sync, as I require offline-first capability. I am building a React Native iOS/Android app with many users having their own data. Therefore I am 'partitioning' by userID. My main use case is mobile and the web app is merely intended to support easy data entry and editing on a laptop or desktop. Therefore not all features of the mobile app need to be replicated in the web app. This is just my personal approach.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. A more specific question. How do you deal with web authentications? Specifically the user password is stored in Realm? 

BTW: I tried to upvote, but it says I am not allowed 

Comment: I saw a discussion  about that here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/help-with-mongo-realm-and-nextjs-with-user-authentication/10901/5

Comment: @xu-han The documentation explains it as well, which might be a good starting point: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/web-graphql/#complete-the-registration-authentication-functions

Comment: Thanks for this . This has helped a lot.